# Render text based on an array of words

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, dom-manipulation

I am trying to render a new span for each word in an array and assign an indexed style value to each one. I am using the JavaScript .map function to try to achieve this, however the text is not showing up on the screen. I feel like I am just missing something that is obvious but I am not sure what it is. Here is my code so far

```
const dummyData = ["Bebesh", "Bebeshes", "crime", "Bob", "fighters", "Well", "freeze", "controll", "strangth"]


const injectedContent = dummyData.map(word => {
  var newWord = document.createElement("span").style = `--i: ${dummyData.indexOf(word)}`.textContent= word
  console.log(getComputedStyle(newWord))
})
```

When I try to console.log the computed styles of the newWord var I get the following error:

```
'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
```

Comment: You can't chain like that. `style` returns the style. create your `newWord` in one statement, then set the style in another.

Answer (score 1):

**Alex Motor** check the below solution.

```js
const dummyData = ["Bebesh", "Bebeshes", "crime", "Bob", "fighters", "Well", "freeze", "controll", "strangth"]
 
const injectedContent = dummyData.map((word,i) => {
  var newWord = document.createElement("span"); 
 newWord.setAttribute("style", "background-color:"+i);
 newWord.textContent=`--${i}:${word}`;
  console.log(newWord)
})
```